# Javascript: should sub/child objects use a dependency instantiated by their parent, or should they instantiate their own instance of the dependency?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My parent module async loads jquery3, in way that jquery3 is scoped to my parent module. In the parent I also load other submodules that use jquery. Should I instantiate jquery in these submodules themselves, or should I pass a reference to my parent's jquery to the submodules? Each of submodules is an object factory. Maybe this is splitting hairs, but I'm working on performance optimizations. Webpack allows me to use the same network call to load my jquery module for availability in all my submodules, so I guess I'm wondering what's a better pattern for runtime performance. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not too concerned about a handful of modules instantiating their own jquery/gasp/react/etc but then I start to think about an app that might use hundreds/thousands of objects ...

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*instantiate their own instance of the dependency*". A dependency, such as the whole jQuery library, is shared between all modules that depend on it. You only instantiate your own objects when you actually call `$(…)`.

Comment: Hi Bergi :-) I'm saving my src modules in their own files. Webpack allows me to generate modules in their own bundle files. At runtime, I can async load a module file then use that module's factory/constructor/etc to instantiate an object. Parent's instance of jquery isn't available to the submodules unless I make it so. In this scenario, would you pass a ref to parent's jquery or in each submodule (as in parent) I can: import( /* webpackChunkName: "jquery3" */ "jquery3").then((resolvedfrompromise)=>{$ = resolvedfrompromise}) Maybe under the hood Webpack actually uses the same instance of jq3?

Comment: I'm leaning towards passing the ref, but I'm wondering if anyone will say "maintaining your modules will be so much easier if you load their dependencies inside themselves." Or maybe bring up something I don't know/haven't thought of.

Comment: There will only ever be a single instance of each module, a single factory/constructor/etc. This is not a quality of Webpack, that's how modules work in general. You should simply write `import $ from 'jquery'` in all your files, and `$` will be an alias for one and the same thing everywhere. Much simpler than passing dependencies down to your submodules. The only advantage I could see in that would be if you are asynchronously loading them and passing them would greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Yeah, I am async loading these dependencies and I want to control which versions of which dependencies are in scope for a given module. Yeah maybe it's best to do things a standard way ... I've been burrowing down a Webpack dynamic import rabbit hole to see where it leads. I really like being able to generate separate named dependency bundles just by one statement though ...

Comment: You have loaded multiple different versions of the same dependency? That's a hassle for the build tools.

Comment: Just the opposite. I've worked out how to only output 1 copy/bundle of each dependency - yet also make sure that specific modules can use specific versions of specific dependencies. I integrate various codebases into a "working whole" and these codebases use their own versions of certain libs, specifically jquery.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi is right, I'm gonna set up the global libs using SplitChunksPlugin cachegroups and use dynamic imports only for conditionally loaded modules. Time for testing.